# how to change scrollbar color in wp8.1

Tags: c#, xaml

i have this code in one of the pages

```
  <FlipView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="Flip" Grid.Row="1" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView" AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details" TabIndex="1"
          DataContext="{Binding RssModel}"
          d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/Assets/Data/RssDataSource.json, Type=vm:RssViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Rss1DetailDetail}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FlipItemStyle}">

</FlipView>
```

i cant see the scrollbar because the background is white and i can see it when i set background to another color.
how i can change scrollbar color to app foreground color (globally).
i know it should be on styles but i want the exact code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brushes you find here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710190.aspx can be overridden if you put a new one into your app resources with the same key. For example the key for the scrollbar background is probably the `ScrollBarTrackBackgroundThemeBrush`, so for a red background just add the line `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarTrackBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />` to your resources.

Edit:

Correct key is: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarPanningBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFCDCDCD"/>`

Comment: thanks. this is the exact line to change scroll bar color. <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarPanningBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFCDCDCD"/>

please edit your reply to mark as answer